# Dimensions of underlying real spaces and dimensions of complexifications

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry

I still have a problem with the idea of complexification of a vector space:

One can define the underlying real vector space of the complex vector space $V$ by simply taking all vectors of $V$ and restricting the complex scalar multiplication to only real scalars.

It then gets clear that the elements $v$ and $iv$ for $v \in V\setminus \left\{0\right\}$ are linearly independent if only real scalar multiplication is allowed. Therefore if $\left(v_1,\dots,v_n\right)$ is a complex basis, then $\left(v_1, iv_1,\dots,v_n,iv_n\right)$ is a real basis and therefore it is $\dim_\mathbb{R} V = 2 \dim_\mathbb{C} V$.

At the same time it holds to be that for the complexification $V_\mathbb{C}$ of a real vector space $V$ it is $\dim_\mathbb R(V) = \dim_\mathbb{C}(V_\mathbb{C})$.

My Problem is now that because of my understanding of the complexification, I think that $V$ is the underlying real Part of $V_\mathbb{C}$ and therefore one of these two equalities can't be true. I'm pretty sure however that both these equations are true and that the problem is that $V$ is not the underlying real part of $V_\mathbb{C}$.

Therefore I would be really thankful if someone could explain to me how all these different spaces are really related to each other.

EDIT: I tried it with the simple complex space $\mathbb C$ its underlying real part should be $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is fine with the formula abouve. At the same time the complexification of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{C}$ which is also fine with the other formula. Is this correct? If so this would constitute an example for why $V$ is not the underlying real part of $V_\mathbb{C}$ since $\mathbb{R} \neq \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: "I think that $V$  is the underlying real Part of $V_{\mathbb{C}}$" Do you mean that, as a real vector space, $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ is isomorphic to $V$? If so, that is false. If not, what did you mean?

Comment: I just edited my question again as an example came to my mind when I was reading my question again. But I think I meant exactly what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that

$$V_{\mathbb{C}} := V\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C} = \{v\otimes 1 + w\otimes i \mid v, w \in V\}.$$

The map $V\oplus V \to V_{\mathbb{C}}$ given by $(v, w) \mapsto v\otimes 1 + w\otimes i$ is an isomorphism of real vector spaces, so $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}(V_{\mathbb{C}}) = \dim_{\mathbb{R}}(V\oplus V) = 2\dim_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$. That is, the underlying real vector space of $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ is not $V$ but (is isomorphic to) $V\oplus V$.